# Problem in multi thread encryption with python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I want to write a script for encrypte a Specified folder files
I find a script for this work from github
But my work in encrypt big folders is slow
I now want to work with multithread for to speed up
But I can't work with threading library

My code for encrypting existing files in a folder at a low speed

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random
import os

def discoverFiles(startpath):
    extensions = [
        'mp3'
    ]

    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        for i in files:
            absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, i))
            ext = absolute_path.split('.')[-1]
            if ext in extensions:
                yield absolute_path

def encrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    outputFile = i + '.enc'
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = Random.new().read(16)

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

def getKey(password):
    hasher = SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8'))
    return hasher.digest()

path = raw_input("Enter your path : ") ; path = str(path)
password = raw_input("Enter your key : ") ; password = str(password)

x = discoverFiles(path)

for i in x:
    encrypt(getKey(password),i)
    os.remove(i)
```

I know for this work we must work with threading library , but I can't work with this library

Please help me for this work...

Comment: AES is CPU-bound; use multiprocessing.

Comment: So bad
There is no solution?

Comment: It's either multiprocessing or generators. First, I would suppress `x` variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should establish that the AES encryption is indeed the factor that makes this slow. It is highly likely that the I/O is much more important. You can check this by removing the encryption from the equation and just copy the files.

Usually disks (and even SSD's) are fast for sequential reads / writes. So it would be a bad idea to read out the files in multi-threaded fashion from a single folder. If you *must* use multi-threading, then create a single thread to read / write the files, and then distribute the chunks over multiple threads for encryption.

However, CBC-encryption is not very useful for this, as each block depends on the output of the previous block (i.e. it is sequential), using e.g. CTR mode would allow separate chunks to be encrypted at the same time. Furthermore, with CTR mode you can *cache the keystream* which could significantly speed up operation as well. You can cache the key stream by encrypting chunks consisting of zero bytes.

For really fast encryption you might as well look at random access using memory mapping files. That *might* be faster than streaming files, although generally the O/S already caches the file in memory anyway.

If AES is the culprit then you should look if AES-NI is enabled. PyCryptodome seems to support AES-NI, so it *should* be used to speed up AES encryption / decryption.

Finally, if you're not smart enough to remove `getKey(password)` from the loop then nobody might be able to help you. Please profile your application. You should replace `getKey(password)` by a password based key derivation function like PBKDF2 to be secure for "common" user passwords.

Comment: `with CTR mode you can cache the keystream` can you please point to a python implementation? I've searched all over and only found algorithmic explanations, but no libraries

Comment: Sorry, but that would be as much a search for me as for you...

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you spoke from experience with using this method.

Comment: I've implemented CTR mode encryption, e.g. using an *all zero input* and a generic CTR encryption algorithm (which generates the key stream itself) as well as directly creating the key stream by encrypting multiple counter blocks using ECB mode. But I did not do this in Python. So experience: yes, but pointing to a library that does this: no.